# Ways to identify if a clickable element is below the mouse pointer across any UI

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using C# for application development and my requirement is to automate mouse click on any clickable item. 
**For example**, if the mouse pointer is over any icon in the explorer or desktop or consider the mouse pointer is on any app's clickable item/UI element say button for some time interval(like 3 secs) my application should get a notification/callback or is there any way to identify if the icon is on a clickable UI element or any other way of doing the same.

Comment: Have you tried with anything like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getchildatpoint?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Or [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/using-ui-automation-for-automated-testing)

Comment: Can someone please tell me why my question is downvoted? Whoever downvoted at least tell the reason and down vote.

Comment: @CetinBasoz i think ths is is usefull only for the forms created by me. Not for the entire windows.

Comment: @Fixation thanks i will have a look . It looks interesting

Comment: @pra7, yes I didn't mean spying.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I have a requirement and this forum is the best in the world for the suggestions. if the question doesn't make any sense then it's fine which is not in this case. But, I got good suggestions from geeks. If Questions are of no use to you then u can please ignore. If you downvote a valid one then people won't see that question as it is having negative votes.

Comment: I didn't down vote.

Comment: Oh ok .. I just said my view ...I hope people will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research i am able to achieve this by using **UI AUTOMATION** thanks to @Fixation. I am using `InvokePattern` for buttons, `TextPattern` for EditBoxes and `TableItemPattern` for tables.

**Following is the code:**

```
static void main(int[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point mouse = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position; 
        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new System.Windows.Point(mouse.X, mouse.Y));
        if (element == null)
        {
            // no element under mouse
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Element at position " + mouse + " is '" + element.Current.Name + "'");

        object pattern;
        if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
        {
            ValuePattern valuePattern = (ValuePattern)pattern;

            Console.WriteLine(" Value=" + valuePattern.Current.Value);
        }

        if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
        {
            InvokePattern invokePattern = (InvokePattern)pattern;

            //invokePattern.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine(" invokePattern=" + invokePattern.ToString());
        }

        if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TableItemPattern.Pattern, out pattern))
        {
            TableItemPattern tableItemPattern = (TableItemPattern)pattern;

            Mouse.MoveTo(new Point(mouse.X, mouse.Y));
            Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left); // Install Microsoft.TestApi from Nuget

            Console.WriteLine(" TableItemPattern=" + tableItemPattern.ToString());
        }  
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!